# Reading data posted to a hook

Tags: php

I have a php functon that receives data from a web service. I have set the function to act as my data receiver

Data posted to my hook looks like this

```
service_name=M-PESA&business_number=896747&transaction_reference=LHL8XS8N1K&internal_transaction_id=7874122&transaction_timestamp=2017-08-21T18%3A42%3A17Z&transaction_type=buygoods&account_number=N%2FA&sender_phone=%2B254720069005&first_name=RON&middle_name=&last_name=AVERY&amount=2.0&currency=Ksh&signature=Z5RI5VtwyI9T2xHgI2GVW8LmnIw%3D&username=very%40gmail.com&password=droid2090
```

My code looks like this

```
public function webhook()
    {
    $post_content = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $webhook = json_decode($post_content);
    $amount = $webhook["amount"];
    $telephone = $webhook["sender_phone"];
    $code = $webhook["transaction_reference"];
    $date_updated = time();
    $id = rand(3,1000);
    $status = 'unseen';

    $data = array(
    'id' => $id,
   'amount' => $amount,
   'telephone' => $telephone,
   'code' => $code,
   'date_updated' => $date_updated,
   'status' => $status
   );

   $this->db->insert('dbo.mpesa', $data);
    }
```

For some reason, i am not able to get the data with my code below although i can see the hook is reached by the web service as it inserts null to the database.

Am i getting the data posted wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not whats being posted back to your webservice... so json_decode will return null.

Your most likely looking to use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) instead.

> void parse_str ( string $encoded_string [, array &$result ] )
>
> Parses encoded_string as if it were the query string passed via a URL
>   and sets variables in the current scope (or in the array if result is
>   provided).

With the utilisation of the second parameter, which will put the data into your `$webhook` variable as an array:

```
$post_content = file_get_contents("php://input");

parse_str($post_content, $webhook);
```

--

Sidenote:

You won't want to set `'id' => $id`, because this will break randomly and once the `3,1000` pool of ids are taken (presuming this is an auto-increment id).